# How to send and receive from MSMQ in the same project with WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, msmq

I want to use WCF to get and send from/to MSMQ. `FeedWorker` method will take message from MQ(from queue1) and give to a thread that will process the message and then save the result to `queue2`. `FeedWorker` and `ProcessCustomer` in the same project.

```
public void FeedWorker()
{
    while(true)
    {
        var msg = GetFromMQ();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessCustomer, msg);
    }
}
public void ProcessCustomer(object o)
{
    // Do some work
    // ...
    SentToMQ(result);
}
```

To achieve this I thought to do the following using `netMsmqBinding`.

```
namespace Test 
{
    public class WcfService : IWcfService
    {
        public void Get(Customer customer)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessCustomer, customer);
        }
        public void SaveResult(string result)
        { }
    }

    public void FeedWorker()
    {
        using (var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfService)))
        {
            serviceHost.Open();
        }
    }

    public void ProcessCustomer(object o)
    {
        // Do some work
        // ...
        WcfServiceClient.SaveResult(result);
    }
}
```

I feel that I do something wrong. And as I did it I cannot receive and send to different queues. How to implement this?

Comment: I think you might be confusing ThreadPool with MSMQ. You need to google MSMQ. I don't see anywhere in your code where you're instantiating an actual MSMQ.

Comment: @BobHorn, when `WcfService` is hosted it uses `netMsmqBidning` to listen to MSMQ and when there is any message `Get` method is invoked and `ProcessCustomer` is processed. At the end the result is saved in MSMQ through `WcfServiceClient.SaveResult`. Because I use `netMsmqBinding` the result will sent through MSMQ

Comment: @BobHorn, how I do that I could get messages from MSMQ and save result to MSMQ with WCF? I've read a few articles, but I still don't understand how to implement it. Do I need 2 separate services?

Comment: I'm not sure that I can help you. Once you explained your approach, I realized that's different than how I do it. When I send and receive from a queue, I simply instantiate a MessageQueue use that to send and receive. I'm not familiar with your approach. You might want to verify that you're not getting an exception, and message queuing needs to be installed on each machine.

Comment: @BobHorn, the queues is on ONE machine. I need to read and write to MSMQ in 2 different queues in the same machine using WCF. I get message from one queue, process it and save the result to other queue. Later there will something that will take those results and process them(in future)

Comment: @BobHorn, do you have any idea how I can do it?

Comment: Not your way. I could show you how *I* send and receive from a queue, if that would help.